# Can somebody explain the simplification of my polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Here's the equation on Wolfram:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=alternate+forms+of+t%5E3%28t%2B1%29%5E-1

Can anyone explain to me how that simplification works, step by step?

Comment: Long division. $t$ goes into $t^3$ $t^2$ "times", carry down $t^2\cdot(t-1)$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just polynomial long division. But you can also try to write $t^3$ as a polynomial in $(t+1)$ with leftover terms, which amounts to the same thing. Explicitly:

$$\frac{t^3}{t+1}=\frac{(t+1)t^2-t^2}{t+1}=\frac{(t+1)t^2-(t+1)t+t}{t+1}=\frac{(t+1)t^2-(t+1)t+(t+1)1-1}{t+1}$$

Then you can divide out $(t+1)$ everywhere but the last term to get

$$\frac{t^3}{t+1}=\boxed{t^2-t+1-\frac{1}{t+1}}$$

Do you see how this is working? At each step, I put a $(t+1)$ in place of a factor of $t$, but this introduces an extra term which I must then subtract to compensate so I don't change the value  as we move along.